# Unable to access NTPD server except on loopback address Centos 6

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, port, centos6, ntpd

I can only get results from:

```
ntpq -p localhost
or
ntpq -p 127.0.0.1
```

If, from the same server, I try it as
either the external IP address or domain name
then it times out with no response.

```
ntpq -p files.tickzoom.com
or
ntpq -p 50.57.65.92
```

Those both time out from the same machine.

I disabled `iptables`. So `iptables -L` shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The goal, actually is to access ntpd from other machines.
But they can't access that IP or DNS either even with
firewall off.

At first I went round and round with `iptables` rules
before disabling `iptables` and realizing I can't do this
even with the firewall off.

Please clue my in to what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to modify the ntp configuration `/etc/ntp.conf` file to allow requests to the other interfaces of the server besides the loopback. The entry to modify is the `noquery` field in the `restrict` line. The `noquery` field prevents everyone from querying the status of your time server.

For IPv4,

```
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
```

change to

```
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer query
```

Then restart the ntp service. You might need to do more reading on the `modify`, `peer`, and `query` field in the `restrict` for a better setup.

At the same time, make sure ntp is listening on all interfaces using netstat, using the `-u` switch for udp

`netstat -anu | grep 123`

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           19339/ntpd
```

Comment: This was "spot on"! You rock. It works now. And, yes, I found docs on the ntpd restrict command and your suggestion to only open query is excellent.

Comment: hey since you solve it so quickly, why not upvote my question. Just a thought.